# The delta function in physics

Tags: dirac-delta

In physics, do we have
\begin{align}
\frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)} =(1-q^{-1}) \delta(y)?
\end{align}
If $y \not\to 1$, then 
\begin{align}
\frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)} = 0.
\end{align}
If $y \to 1$, then
\begin{align}
& \frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)} \\
& =(1-q^{-1})\left(\frac{1}{1-y} + \frac{1}{1-y^{-1}}\right) \\
& = (1-q^{-1})\left(\sum_{n \geq 0} y^n + \sum_{m \leq 0} y^m\right) \\
& =\left (1-q^{-1}\right)\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} y^n + 1\right) \\
& = \left(1 - q^{-1}\right)\left(\delta(y)+1\right).
\end{align}
Where is the mistake in my computations? Thank you very much.

Edit: q is a complex number and y is a variable. This type of computations happen in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08533).

I think that maybe the following computations are correct.
\begin{align}
& \frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)} \\
& =\left(1-q^{-1}y\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-y} + \frac{y^{-1}}{1-y^{-1}}\right) \\
& = \left(1-q^{-1}y\right)\left(\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} y^n\right) \\
& = \left(1-q^{-1}y\right)\delta(y) \\
& = \left(1-q^{-1} \right)\delta(y).
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain what $q$ and $y$ represent?

Comment: @fibonatic, thank you very much. I edited the post.  q is a complex number and y is a variable. This type of computations happen in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08533).

Comment: Something is not very healthy here. A Dirac delta is only really well defined under an integral. It is difficult to see how the left-hand side in your first expression, which seems like a straightforward algebraic expression, can lead to a expression that contain a Dirac delta function.

Comment: @flippiefanus I think OP means the kronecker delta, not the Dirac delta

Comment: There's nothing in this question that makes it specific to physics.

Comment: gauge theory couplings is an application. Back to physics.S.E ?

Comment: @LJR: At a first view I can already spot a problem: if $y \to 1$ AND $y \ge 1$, then the series $\sum y^n$ does NOT converge, therefore it is not a replacement for $\frac 1 {1-y}$.

Comment: "In physics", I could not say, but in mathematics,
$$\frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)}$$ is undefined when $y=1$ and, for every $y\ne1$, this is $$
\frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)} =\frac{y-q}{q(y-1)}-\frac{q-y}{q(1-y)}=0.$$

Comment: My respsonse: it is false in mathematics, so to find out whether it is OK in physics, ask in http://physics.stackexchange.com/ ... but it seems they have already rejected it by migrating it here.  So you are out of luck.

Comment: @AlexM.: It's even worse: Since the sum goes over $n\in\mathbb Z$, it *never* converges: If $|y| \ge 1$, the positive exponent side diverges, if $0<|y|\le1$,the negative exponent side diverges, and if $y=0$ the negative exponent terms are not even well defined.

Comment: *Typo in my comment: Replace "when $y=1$" by "when $y=0$ or $y=1$"' and "for every $y\ne1$" by "for every $y\ne0,1$", since for $y=0$ the expression $$\frac{q^{-1}y-1}{y-1}-\frac{qy^{-1}-1}{q(y^{-1}-1)}$$ is undefined as well.